# Python versions cannot locate modules in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

In my Linux (ubuntu 12.04) system, I have python2.7.3 in `/usr/bin` and python2.7.5 in  `/usr/local/bin`

The modules like numpy are installed into `/usr/share/pyshared` (by default when I use `sudo apt-get install python-numpy`)

python2.7.3 can import the modules without any problems, while python2.7.5 cannot locate the modules. I have added `/usr/share/pyshared` to `$PATH` variable using `/etc/profile`, but python2.7.5 still cannot find the modules.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you need 2.7.3 and 2.7.5?

Comment: I dont need 2.7.3. but when I "upgraded" from ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04, they both appeared this way.

Comment: what do you get if you try "sudo update-alternatives --config python"

Comment: it says "update alternatives: error: no alternatives for python"

Comment: and "python --version"?

Comment: it says ==> Python 2.7.5

Comment: have you tried sudo pip install numpy? From your error below it sounds like you have a broken install of numpy. I would apt-get remove it and try install with pip

Comment: I did, but still the same multi array problem and a few system crashes appeared as well. I will try to do a clean install of ubuntu. Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

you can set up [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) in your environment before starting python-2.7.5:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/pyshared
```

or you can do this at the start of your local python scripts:

```
import sys
sys.path.prepend('/usr/share/pyshared')
```

Comment: Thanks, there is progress. Now, both versions can locate numpy but both throw this error==> ImportError: No module named multiarray